# ifelse , hide unmatched elements in R

Tags: r

I want to hide the unmatched elements using ifelse. How do I do that?
my code is:

`se <- sqrt(1:n)
ifelse(se==as.integer(se), se, "WANT THIS INVISIBLE")`

so far I can only make display other values such as FALSE, 0 or other but no invisible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are trying to do exactly, but if the point is to avoid the quotation marks in the console, you could wrap the `ifelse` with `cat`:

```
n <- 100
se <- sqrt(1:n)
cat(ifelse(se==as.integer(se), se, ""))
```

Which results in:

```
1   2     3       4         5           6             7               8                 9                   10
```

Comment: Hi I want hide all the unmatched values and only display the ones that are a match. I tried your suggestion but the wide space in between doesn't allow good format and there's an red arrow after the outcome, prompting to enter something else. Is there another way to hide unmatched outcomes?

Comment: To take care of the extra spaces you could do this: `cat(ifelse(se==as.integer(se), se, "\b"))`  I really don't know what you mean about a red arrow after the outcome though.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you want or have to use `ifelse`, but if that is not a requirement you can just do `se[se == as.integer(se)]`